# What's an easier way to navigate the compiler view?

Tags: chapters, navigation, sharelatex

ShareLaTeX has 3 columns when a project is open--a menu column on the left, the LaTex code in the middle, and the compiler view on the right. I'm using ShareLaTeX to write my PhD dissertation--a very long document. As I'm writing, I frequently wonder if there isn't an easier way to navigate to sections of the compiler view.

For example, let's say I'm making changes in Chapter 3 but I want to quickly skip back to Chapter 1 for just a second. As far as I can tell, I need to scroll up to Chapter 1, make the change, and then scroll all the way back down to Chapter 3 to commence writing.

What's an easier way to do this? Feel free to drop in any other navigation lifehacks you can think of for long documents.

Comment: Why don't you ask in ShareLaTeX? This seems more a question for them than about (La)TeX itself.

Comment: Welcome! I can only say 'rather you than me'. I assume that you have a good backup strategy. Even so, this strikes me as a dangerous plan. Put it this way: if ShareLaTeX disappears 24 hours before the deadline for submission, what is your plan B? If ShareLaTeX update their installation of TeX 24 hours before your deadline and that update breaks your document in significant and mysterious ways, what's plan B? As for navigation, for a long document you want a single master file and each chapter in a separate `.tex` file which you `\include{}`. Then you can also compile them separately.

Comment: Also, I assume your dissertation will not include any confidential or sensitive data. But, as I say, even in the best case, I wouldn't want to run this kind of risk myself.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why don't you attempt to answer my question. Is there a way to navigate a compiled text in your compiler, whatever you choose to use?